# Lagrange multiplier and semidefinite programming

Tags: convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, semidefinite-programming

suppose we have a primal semidefinite programming. for finding its dual we use Lagrange multiplier $w_i$ for each semidefinite constraint. If the Lagrange multiplier be zero for one constraint what we could say for its related complementary constraint in dual?

Answer (score 1):

For all you ever wanted to know about this, check out [Boyd and Vanderberghe's Convex Optimization](http://www.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/), especially the part on KKT. In fact, that page advertises a MOOC on Convex Optimization...